# How to assign a user control to an extended code behind?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a series of ASP.NET pages that are pretty much the same, except for some abstract properties in the code behind.

Each page (/default.aspx) includes a user control:

```
<UI:SingleRaterControl runat="server" />
```

Previously, the various code behinds were copy and pastes of essentially the same thing.  In each version of /default.aspx.cs there was a protected property that would hold the user control.

```
public class _default: SingleRaterBase
{
    protected SingleRaterControl singleRaterControl;
    ...
}
```

In an effort to reduce the amount of code I have to maintain, I created at abstract class called EProfileDefault that would hold all the common code of the _default classes (each _default class is in a different namespace).

So now I have

```
public abstract class EProfileDefault: SingleRaterBase
{
    protected SingleRaterControl singleRaterControl;
    ...
}
```

and each _default class has

```
public class _default : EProfileDefault
{
    ...
}
```

However, the SingleRaterControl is no longer getting automatically assigned to the code behind.

Is this because ASP.NET magic will only automatically assign the user control to the immediate instance of the code behind class, as long as it has the same name (as suggested by this [article](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18843))?

If so, is it possible to manually find and assign the user control?

Comment: But why *don't* you give the ID of the control "singleRaterControl", and then everything should just work.

Comment: That would be the logical thing to do, wouldn't it. So I did, and it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @aquinas, give the control an ID, and the control will get assigned to the protected property with the same name as the ID of the control.